# How do I configure the Razor *.cshtml editor's C# compiler settings outside of an ASP.NET project?

Tags: razor, visual-studio-2017

(This is not a duplicate of [Print and/or modify the c# version that the razor compiler service uses to compile cshtml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21991886/print-and-or-modify-the-c-sharp-version-that-the-razor-compiler-service-uses-to) because I'm using RazorGenerator, not ASP.NET, the translation from .cshtml to .cs happens every time I press the Save button in Visual Studio, so adding assembly references or NuGet packages to my project won't help)

I have a C# Class Library project using RazorGenerator (a Visual Studio extension that transpiles `.cshtml` to `.cs` sources). RazorGenerator itself works fine and my .cshtml files are converted to cs correctly without any problems considering I'm using C# 7.3 language features and types defined in custom assemblies.

The problem is Visual Studio's own .cshtml designer (independent of RazorGenerator) seems to default to the C# 4.0 compiler version and doesn't even load `System.Core.dll` - so when viewing .cshtml files in the Visual Studio editor I get peppered with error messages that shouldn't be there:

> "Feature 'out variable declaration' is not available in C# 4. Please use language version 7.0 or greater."

[image]

and broken namespace imports because it isn't loading assemblies:

[image]

I saw these SO posts:

- [Where to configure Razor page language version to C# 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32012051/where-to-configure-razor-page-language-version-to-c-sharp-6)
- [C# 6.0 Features Not Working with Visual Studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27968963/c-sharp-6-0-features-not-working-with-visual-studio-2015/31548221#31548221)

...which suggest adding the NuGet `Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform` package to the project and restarting Visual Studio, however that did not solve the issue.

Comment: I really wonder, why there is no reaction... Either it is so trivial, that it should be obvious, or nobody knows :-) (Or it's just not possible!)
And we don't seem to be the first ones to encounter this annoyance: https://github.com/RazorGenerator/RazorGenerator/issues/177